# Integrated iSight camera on Apple Cinematic Display does not work with ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, webcam, external-monitor, apple

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 machine, running on a System76 Lemur Pro.

I have connected the machine through the USB-C connector to an Apple Cinematic Display, which I am using as my external monitor. The Apple monitor comes with an integrated iSight camera. I am unable to enable/access the camera from my machine.

### What I have tried

- Installed the facetimehd firmware, even though this is probably for Ubuntu running on a Mac machine: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MactelSupportTeam/AppleiSight
- Installed the UVC driver.

### Debugging

```bsh
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Chicony USB2.0 Camera: Chicony  (usb-0000:00:14.0-7):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1

$ lsmod | grep uvc
uvcvideo               98304  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  2 facetimehd,uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  3 videobuf2_v4l2,facetimehd,uvcvideo
videodev              225280  4 videobuf2_v4l2,facetimehd,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common

$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b685 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Chicony USB2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:0939 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd USB Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is there a way to use the iSight camera from my laptop?

Comment: I am connecting to an Apple  display that has an in-built camera. The camera is an iSight camera, and I have the drivers for that afaict. I will try again through Apple support. Let me know if you have other ideas. Particularly, I was curious about what the output of `lsmod | grep uvc` meant, since it shows facetimehd as one of the outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Since the display is connecting through USB-C, it's probably a Thunderbolt display.  To use the camera integrated into the Thunderbolt display I have, I needed to authorize it first.

First, find the device UUID:

```
$ boltctl list
 ● Apple Thunderbolt Display
   ├─ type:          peripheral
   ├─ name:          Thunderbolt Display
   ├─ vendor:        Apple, Inc.
   ├─ uuid:          204f6800-0100-0100-ffff-ffffffffffff
   ├─ status:        connected
   │  ├─ domain:     c5030000-0092-9088-a0b0-150c24127020
   │  └─ authflags:  none
   ├─ connected:     Fri 25 Sep 2020 08:02:57 PM
   └─ stored:        no
```

The UUID is the long hexadecimal string on the "uuid" line.

Next, enroll the display:

```
$ boltctl enroll 204f6800-0100-0100-ffff-ffffffffffff
```

You'll be prompted for your password, and then the webcam should show up on the list of cameras.

If you don't want the authorization preserved after you unplug the device, use `boltctl authorize <uuid>` instead. If `boltctl` isn't on your machine, install it with `sudo apt install bolt`.